# File upload vulnerability

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, javascript, file-upload

I am trying to pentest a webapp challenge. 
Is the following control code vulnerable to file upload? I would like to upload a php shell...

I am able to upload `shell.php.jpg` file but I receive the error when I load the file location.

```
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }
}

var input_file = document.getElementById('image_file');
input_file.onchange = function() {
    var extension = $('#image_file').val().split('.').pop();
    switch (extension.toLowerCase()){
        case 'png':
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            break;
        default:
            alert('Invalid file name');
            $('#image_file').val("")
    }

    return;
};
```

Comment: Is there just client-side validation? What happens if you simply disable JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're only looking at the file extension.  This is not effective.  For a description of why, and a list of viable protections, please refer to [the OWASP article on "Unrestricted File Upload"](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload).

Excerpt:  (Some of this may not be directly applicable to your environment, but I'm not editing those out.)

> **Using Black-List for Files’ Extensions**
>
> Some web applications still use only a black-list of extensions to
>   prevent from uploading a malicious file.
>
> - It is possible to bypass this protection by using some extensions which are executable on the server but are not mentioned in the list.
>     (Example: “file.php5”, “file.shtml”, “file.asa”, or “file.cer”)
> - Sometimes it is possible to bypass this protection by changing some letters of extension to the capital form (example: “file.aSp” or
>     “file.PHp3”).
> - Using trailing spaces and/or dots at the end of the filename can sometimes cause bypassing the protection. These spaces and/or dots at
>     the end of the filename will be removed when the file wants to be
>     saved on the hard disk automatically. The filename can be sent to the
>     server by using a local proxy or using a simple script (example:
>     “file.asp ... ... . . .. ..”, “file.asp ”, or “file.asp.”).
> - A web-server may use the first extension after the first dot (“.”) in the file name or use a specific priority algorithm to detect the
>     file extension. Therefore, protection can be bypassed by uploading a
>     file with two extensions after the dot character. The first one is
>     forbidden, and the second one is permitted (example: “file.php.jpg”).
> - In case of using IIS6 (or prior versions), it might be possible to bypass this protection by adding a semi-colon after the forbidden
>     extension and before the permitted extension (example:
>     “file.asp;.jpg”).
> - In case of using IIS6 (or prior versions), it might be possible to bypass this protection by putting an executive file such as ASP with
>     another extension in a folder which ends with an executive extension
>     such as “.asp” (example: “folder.asp\file.txt”). Besides, it is
>     possible to create a directory just by using a file uploader and ADS
>     (Alternate Data Stream). In this method, filename should end with
>     “::$Index_Allocation” or “:$I30:$Index_Allocation” to create a
>     directory instead of a file (example:
>     “newfolder.asp::$Index_Allocation” creates “newfolder.asp” as a new
>     directory).
> - This protection can be completely bypassed by using the e.g. control characters like Null (0x00) after the forbidden extension and
>     before the permitted one. In this method, during the saving process
>     all the strings after the Null character will be discarded. Putting a
>     Null character in the filename can be simply done by using a local
>     proxy or by using a script (example: “file.asp%00.jpg”). Besides, it
>     would be perfect if the Null character is inserted directly by using
>     the Hex view option of a local proxy such as Burpsuite or Webscarab in
>     the right place (without using %).
> - It is also possible to create a file with a forbidden extension by using NTFS alternate data stream (ADS). In this case, a “:” sign will
>     be inserted after the forbidden extension and before the permitted
>     one. As a result, an empty file with the forbidden extension will be
>     created on the server (example: “file.asp:.jpg”). Attacker can try to
>     edit this file later to execute his/her malicious codes. However, an
>     empty file is not always good for an attacker. So, there is an
>     invented method by the author of this paper in which an attacker can
>     upload a non-empty shell file by using the ADS. In this method, a
>     forbidden file can be uploaded by using this pattern:
>     “file.asp::$data.”.
> - In Windows Servers, it is possible to replace the files by using their short-name (8.3). (example: “web.config” can be replaced by
>     uploading “web~1.con”)  Sometimes combination of the above can lead to
>     bypassing the protections.
>
> **Using White-List for Files’ Extensions**
>
> Many web applications use a white-list to accept the files’
>   extensions. Although using white-list is one of the recommendations,
>   it is not enough on its own. Without having input validation, there is
>   still a chance for an attacker to bypass the protections.
>    - the 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th methods of last section apply here as well. 
>    - The list of permitted extensions should be reviewed as it can contain malicious extension as well. For instance, in case of having
>   “.shtml” in the list, the application can be vulnerable to SSI
>   attacks.